# How do you implement asynchronous I/O?

Tags: c#, multithreading, encryption, asynchronous

I'm writing a program that encrypts files, this means I need to read a lot of data, encrypt that data, and write that data to a new file. In an attempt to increase performance, I've tried to multi-thread the process. I've created two blocking collections, using them as queues I read data into a byte array and pass that array into the first blocking collection, I take that array out of the blocking collection, encrypt it and pass it to the second blocking collection where I take that array out and write it to a file.

Although i'm getting improvements on speed, the process is very unreliable. It can start at 30/mb's, peak at 35mb/s and trail of drastically to almost a standstill after about 800Mb have been processed. I have a strong feeling i'm doing this wrong, and I have spent the best part of three hours this afternoon, and even longer yesterday trying to understand how I could instead using filestream.beginread() asynchronously to improve reliability and speed.

Here is the code:

```
   public void Encrypt()
    {

        using (BlockingCollection<Byte[]> EncryptionQueue = new BlockingCollection<Byte[]>(32),
                                          WritingQueue = new BlockingCollection<Byte[]>(32))
        {
            Task readAction = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                FileStream input = new FileStream(DataFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024 * 8);
                BinaryReader binaryInput = new BinaryReader(input);
                ByteTotal = (int)input.Length;
                while (BytesLeft < ByteTotal)
                {
                    EncryptionQueue.Add(binaryInput.ReadBytes(8192));
                    BytesLeft += 8192;
                }
                EncryptionQueue.CompleteAdding();
                input.Close();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


            Task encryptAction = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                RC4Engine StreamCipher = new RC4Engine(this.keyString);
                foreach (Byte[] chunk in EncryptionQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    int len = chunk.Length;
                    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
                    {
                        chunk[x] ^= StreamCipher.OutputByte();
                    }
                    WritingQueue.Add(chunk);
                }
                WritingQueue.CompleteAdding();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


            Task writeAction = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                FileStream output = new FileStream(TempFile.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 1024 * 8);
                foreach (Byte[] chunk in WritingQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    output.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
                }
                output.Close();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Task timerAction = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (BytesLeft < ByteTotal)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    progressReport.Report((BytesLeft / (1024 * 1024)).ToString());
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Task.WaitAll(readAction, encryptAction, writeAction, timerAction);


            // Delete the existing file if it exists
            File.Delete(DataFile.FullName);
            // Rename the temporary file created during encryption to it's final filename.
            File.Move(TempFile.FullName, DataFile.FullName);
        }
```

Progress.report is just a way of updating the ui thread with how many bytes have been encrypted so far.

How would I write this if I were to use Asynchronous I/O?

Comment: I think you should try to figure out if synchronous operations are really what the problem is first.

Comment: Have you considered this much simpler method? You need two buffers. Read the first buffer synchronously, then start encryption and write asynchronously on that buffer. While it is doing that, read the second buffer, also synchronously, then wait for the encryption+write to complete, swap the buffer, and start encryption+write on the new buffer asynchronously and fill the second (swapped) buffer, again synchronously.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How would I do that?

Comment: By employing the usual troubleshooting methods.  In your case, it's mostly about profiling/timing your code, and finding out where the bottleneck is (if any).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this seems like a great method, I can't seem to find any examples of asynchronously reading and writing data, only reading or writing, what would the code look like?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I must have run and timed this code over a thousand times already using a 2gb file, I wasn't able to identify any bottlenecks although i'm sure they're there... I get the feeling I need to take this back to basics

Comment: That's not the kind of timing I'm talking about.  You need to find out *where the code is stalling.*  Or, yeah, write it simpler.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How do you find out where the code is stalling?

Comment: By putting stopwatches around all of the methods and suspect method calls. The one that takes the longest wins.  Or you can use a profiler.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the input, I hadn't even thought of that

Comment: Windows reads ahead automatically. The IO is overlapped with application processing. All of this is moot.

Comment: @usr then why do they have asynchronous read and write?

Comment: @RyanCodrai for all the usually reason one would use async IO. Overlapping things is not the most common one. Async IO saves a thread that would be blocked waiting for example. If you just want to overlap you could do that with threads, too. Async IO has nothing to do with overlapping operations in time.

Comment: @usr My main aim is to try and increase throughput, I'm going to go and do some more reading around the subject, I think I may have to much of a vague view of how operations are processed.